# Escape JSON in Mix shell echo command

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-poison

I have a similar code to this. I want it to echo a valid JSON with quotes on properties so that it can be piped to another command. But while echoing, it is ripping off all the quotes.

```
def test_function() do
  map = %{
    "key1" => 12,
    "key2" => "value1",
  }

  json = Poison.encode!(map)
  IO.inspect(json)

  Mix.Shell.cmd(
    "echo #{json}",
    fn x -> IO.puts(x) end
  )
end
```

**Expected**

```
{"key2":"value1","key1":12}
```

**Actual**

```
{key2:value1,key1:12}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to quote JSON string in single-quotes

```
Mix.Shell.cmd(
  "echo '#{json}'",
  fn x -> IO.puts(x) end
)
```

[Ref](https://elixirforum.com/t/escape-json-in-mix-shell-echo-command/38592/2?u=singla-shivam)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to rely on the OS `echo` command when Elixir `IO` already ties into STDOUT.  I think you may be getting into trouble here because you are sending the result of `IO.inspect` AND the result of `IO.puts` (wrapped in the system's `echo` command) to `STDOUT`, so it's doubling things up and at a minimum, this is confusing, but it probably is invalid as well.

This works for me, given a simple `github.json` file containing

```
{
    "sha": "d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f",
    "commit": {
        "author": {
            "name": "Stephen Dolan",
            "email": "mu@netsoc.tcd.ie",
            "date": "2013-06-22T16:30:59Z"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits/d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f"
}
```

stored alongside a `parse.exs` script with the following:

```
contents = File.read!("github.json")
map = Jason.decode!(contents)

json_str = Jason.encode!(map)
IO.puts(json_str)
```

This decoding and encoding is demonstrates that this is working (substitute `Poison` or whatever as desired).

Now, I can run the following command via `mix run parse.exs` and I see the expected result.  I can also pipe the output as expected, e.g. to `jq`:

```
❯ mix run parse.exs | jq '.sha'
"d25341478381063d1c76e81b3a52e0592a7c997f"
```

Comment: I didn't get it - `You shouldn't need to rely on the OS echo command when Elixir IO already ties into STDOUT`.

Comment: How will I pipe a JSON string to a command?

Comment: I included an example of piping the output to the `jq` command (see above).  `IO.puts` already writes to `STDOUT`, so you don't need to use `echo` or some other OS-specific utility.

Comment: Hm, the solution seems ok, but it does not work with my code. The above code is part of a long running application, so I can not use and pipe the output of running a script.

Comment: Do you mean you have other `IO.puts` statements in your code so you have other things being written to STDOUT?  Maybe you should use `Logger` instead so you have more control over that.  In lieu of that, yeah, quote your value as you posted.

Comment: No, I don't have any `puts` or `inspect` statement. They are here for just debugging. The code is part of a mix task. It creates an k8s config in an elixir map, convert to JSON and creates the api-resource using `kubectl apply -f -`. It may output some info to STDOUT using `Mix.shell().info/1`.